# twofaced file problem

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, windows-7

I'm reading in my program some files from system32 folder; and one of these files (C:\Windows\System32\gdi32.dll) demonstrates a very strange behavior. When I'm reading it from my program, it shows size of 310'784 bytes; and when I view it's size from Explorer, it shows size of 404'480 bytes.
How could that be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most likely explanation is that your program is 32-bit and Explorer is 64-bit. When a 32-bit program opens files in `C:\Windows\System32` (which contains 64-bit DLLs), it's actually redirected to `C:\Windows\SysWOW64` (which contains 32-bit DLLs). The size difference you're seeing is the difference between the `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32.dll` and `C:\Windows\System32\gdi32.dll` files.

For more information, see [KB article 896456](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896456).

Comment: Yeah, you're correct. However, my x32 file manager shows correct file size (the same as Explorer). How can it do that?

Comment: Perhaps it calls Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365743.aspx).