# GetFileSizeEx Returns Incorrect Value on System32 Dir

Tags: c, winapi, filesize, system32

I'm experiencing a very weird problem regarding GetFileSize and GetFileSizeEx APIs.

Both functions work fine on every input file EXCEPT files from the System32 Dir.

For example:

If I use one of the APIs on calc.exe (In System32) I will get a return value of 776192 bytes even though its real size is 918,528 bytes !

This also happens with other executables in System32 (Regedit, calcs ..).

The return value of GetFileSizeEx is TRUE, no error is reported.

If I copy calc.exe to a different dir (Say C:\) the API returns the correct number of bytes.

My guess is files in the System32 dir are some how compressed ?

Or something similar, and the GetFileSize APIs returns its compressed size, and not real size.

Does anybody have any idea why this is happening ?

I'm running Windows 7 SP1.

Comment: _The GetFileSize function retrieves the uncompressed size of a file._ , [GetFileSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364955(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Even if the files were compressed, `GetFileSize/Ex()` reports the **uncompressed** size.  There is a separate `GetCompressedFileSize()` to get the **compressed** size.  So that is not the issue.

Comment: You are a 32-bit application running on a 64-bit system, which means that you are getting [file system redirection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099082/twofaced-file-problem).

Comment: Wow ! I would never though of that, thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You ask for a file under `c:\windows\system32`, but you might be getting files from `c:\windows\syswow64\` instead.

On my system, calc.exe under c:\windows\system32\ is **897KB**. Under syswow64 it's **758KB**.

Read more about the File System Redirector here:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)